# Where are LINQ assemblies located in Windows XP?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, linq

Where are LINQ assemblies located in Windows XP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My earlier answer was incorrect.  The Framework directory under `%WINDIR%` will not contain any of the LINQ assemblies.  It only contains compiler related tasks.  In order to get the LINQ assemblies you have 2 choices.

If you know the full framework is installed, not just the runtime components, then you can grab the reference assemblies from

> %ProgramFiles%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5

Otherwise the best bet is to go through the GAC

For the 64 bit runtime they will be at

> %WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v3.5

Comment: Thanks Jared. I have 3.5 and searched for Linq but couldn't find any. What's the name of the file?

Comment: @Joan, It will be System.Core.dll

Comment: It's very strange, I searched C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework for core, no dll came up.

Answer (score 3):

In the GAC. `System.Core.dll` I think.